# Can't use Adapter inside onResponse

Tags: android

I'm trying to use an Adapter inside an onResponse request, but I'm getting some problems while I have to pass the context to the Adapter.

This is the error:

> CodiciAdapter() in CodiciAdapter cannot be applied to: Expected
>   Parameters: Actual Arguments:   context: android.content.Context
>   this  (anonymous..Codici>>) items:
>   java..Codici> R.layout.activity_listview  (int)
>   response  (java..Codici>)

This is my request:

```
Override
        public void onResponse(List<Codici> response) {


            //ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             //       R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.codici_list);


            CodiciAdapter codiciAdapter = new CodiciAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_listview, response); //what should I use instead of this??

            listView.setAdapter(codiciAdapter);

        }
```

And this is my Adapter:

```
public class CodiciAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private final List<Codici> items;

public CodiciAdapter(Context context, List<Codici> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.items.size();
}

@Override
public Codici getItem(int position) {
    return this.items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return this.items.get(position).hashCode();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Codici item = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView == null) {
        // If convertView is null we have to inflate a new layout

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, null);

        final CodiciViewHolder viewHolder = new CodiciViewHolder();
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        // We set the view holder as tag of the convertView so we can access the view holder later on.
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    // Retrieve the view holder from the convertView
    final CodiciViewHolder viewHolder = (CodiciViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    // Bind the values to the views
    viewHolder.name.setText(item.getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Basically you passing wrong parameters to your constructor..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodiciAdapter's first parameter is `Context`.
`See CodiciAdapter(Context context, List<Codici> items)`.

So when you using `this` inside inner class `this` will point to current class not the Outer one .

Solution is if this class is Activity . then use the code below and remove extra parameter `R.layout.activity_listview`.

```
Override
public void onResponse(List<Codici> response) {
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.codici_list);
    CodiciAdapter codiciAdapter = new CodiciAdapter(YourActivityName.this, response); 
    listView.setAdapter(codiciAdapter);
}
```

Or in other case you need to provide the `Context` .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After I changed that I got a new error.

Answer (score 0):

just remove layout file from constructor

```
CodiciAdapter codiciAdapter = new CodiciAdapter(this,response);
```